# How can I render multiple scaffold table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three different models, controllers and views respectively. They are Project, Stage and Task. I want to render stage in project_controller#show that's done. Project has one-to-many relationship with stage and task has many-to-one relationship with stage. I want to render each stage followed by their tasks and so on for next stage. I have tried to do so but I am getting error.

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      resources :tasks
    end
  end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes(:stages).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
  end
```

projects/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Add Stage", new_project_stage_url(@project), :class=>"button primary small" %>

<br>
<div class="table-scroll">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Stage</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @stages.each do |stage| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= stage.stage %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

tasks/index.html.erb ( i want to add task button and all task associated with stage will be rendered on project show page in table)

```
  <%= link_to 'New Task', new_project_stage_task_url, :class=>"button primary" %>
  <div class="table-scroll">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Task name</th>
          <th>Planned start date</th>
          <th>Planned end date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= task.task_name %></td>
            <td><%= task.planned_start_date %></td>
            <td><%= task.planned_end_date %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is the error you get? Can you paste the stacktrace here?

Comment: when i try to add task code into project show page i get error- No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:project_id, :stage_id]                                                                    <%= link_to 'New Task', new_project_stage_task_url, :class=>"button primary" %>

Comment: ooh, you have to supply the project_id and stage_id to the new_project_stage_task_url. E.g: `new_project_stage_task_url(project_id: project.id, stage_id: stage.id)`

Comment: @NwochaAdim still error -undefined local variable or method `project' for. when i check with @project.id and @stage.id it gives id error

Comment: I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

With the nested resources routes you have, I'm guessing the path to the tasks#index will be:

```
/tasks/:project_id/:stage_id/
```

For this, you'll need to always provide a project_id and stage_id to view tasks. So your tasks#index action should look like:

```
def index
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @stage = @project.stages.find(params[:stage_id])
  @tasks = @stage.tasks
end
```

This way, in your tasks/index.html.erb view, you'll have the @project and @stage instance variables accessible and you can use the correct url:

```
new_project_stage_task_url(project_id: @project.id, stage_id: @stage.id)
```

Comment: Hey i have rendered stage index and add stage button on project#show view. now i wan to render task index and add task button   in project#show with each stage user has created? how can i do that?

Comment: The best way to do this is to have a partial for stage. Such that while looping through each stage, you can render a partial for a stage that will contain the view logic code that displays a task's index.